# How windows detect nearby network printers connected with wifi?

Tags: android, windows, printers

Can some please explain how Windows detect near by printer as Mac OS uses Bonjour to detect them. I want my android device to be detected as printer in the nearby list of Windows. I am using [NSD](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) to register a network service with ipp protocol and it works fine in Mac OS. Now I want the same functionality for Windows as well. Please help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Windows Vista, I believe it uses Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery).

> The component WSDMON in Windows 7 and later uses WS-Discovery to automatically discover WSD-enabled network printers, which show in Network in Windows Explorer, and can be installed by double-clicking on them. In Windows 8 or later installation is automatic. WS-Discovery is enabled by default in networked HP printers since circa 2008.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

Earlier versions of Windows used NetBIOS and SMB but I presume we're talking modern Windows here.

Answer (score 1):

I currently work a technical support position - Windows is not guaranteed to find anything actually. You could have multiple printers on a network, shared in different methods. Printers may also be on separate vlans and you network can also have rules and devices which interfere with these protocols operating.

Instead of relying on the integrity of the users network (which is improbable to account for), you should find your users devices IP address and give the user instructions on how to connect a Windows device to your app.

If you would like to fight Goliath however, read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783789%28v=ws.10%29.aspx